# Ruby on Rails: Will updating from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 cause issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-13.10, ubuntu-13.04

I have RVM installed, I'm just curious if updating will force me into debug mode for hours, or if I would have to reinstall RoR.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should not to change anything with rvm, ruby or rails. There is no reason for that.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted a second opinion =)